# How to use the dynamic shape of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

How can I build a tensorflow graph for the following computation? The question I'm having now is how to use the shape information of tensor A, which has a variable shape size.

```
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,10])
B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,20]))
C = tf.matmul(A, B)
D = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(C), A) # the value of A.shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing the value of a tensor `A` to a placeholder and when you do so you already know the shape of it. I would create another placeholder for a shape that you care about and pass it as well:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,10])
L = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None)

B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,20]))
C = tf.matmul(A, B)
D = tf.multiply(tf.transpose(C), L) // L is a number, matmul does not multiply matrix with a number

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    a = np.zeros((5, 10), dtype=np.float32)
    l = a.shape[0]
    sess.run(D, {A: a, L: l})
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. It's just not perfect because every time you want to fetch D, you have to remember to feed the shape.

Comment: Actually it is a good practice to have a helper which generates all the feed dict and you do something like: `sess.run(<things>, your_dict_helper())`

Comment: I see. Thanks very much!

Comment: This links shows an approach using TensorFlow rather than Python for dealing with the shape:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668786/how-do-you-create-a-dynamic-rnn-with-dynamic-zero-state-fails-with-inference